# How can I move my custom css to the very bottom of the head section?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I have a code, which includes my custom css file to the  of the template:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_css');

function add_custom_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style('custom-styles',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/../../../wp-includes/css/custom.css');
}
```

How can I move my custom.css file to the very bottom of  to override some plugin styles?

Comment: That URL isn't going to work. Why are you putting styles in the wp-includes file anyway?

Comment: this URL work's excellent and is this big difference where to put my custom styles? I don't think that I should put custom style to the template folder

Answer (score 3):

Set the priority argument on [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), the 3rd argument, to something high:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_css', 20 );`

The default is 10, so most styles will be loaded at that priority in the order that the plugins are loaded, so 20 will be after most of them. Increase or decrease that number as required.